# Wildcard for nested list-query

Tags: python, list, nested, wildcard

I've got a nested list and I'd like to check whether `i` is contained on the lowest level of my list (`i` is the first of two elements of one "sublist").

1) Is there a direct way to do this?

2) I tried the following:

```
for i in randomlist:
    if [i,randomlist.count(i)] in list1:
```

Is there a way to replace `randomlist.count(i)` with a wildcard? I tried `*,%,...,` but non of these worked well. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give example of input and output?

Comment: can you add an example of randomlist and desired output? it's hard to understand what you need

Comment: input shows nested list with numbers and their counts in sublists: [[86, 4], [67, 1], [89, 1],...]
output: i need to know whether a number with its count is already in the list (in order not to add it a second time), but the count is unknown during the for loop

Comment: A dictionary may be better suited for keeping a count of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
if any(l[0] == i for l in list1):
```

This will *only* check the first item in each sub-list, which is effectively the same as having a wild-card second element.

Comment: That syntax is illegal.  I think you want to remove the `in`.

Comment: Why is it illegal syntax? I've run the program with and without `in` and for the case without it Python displayed a syntax error.

Comment: @user3017048 iCodez was referring to another `in`, which I've since edited out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is the actual problem:

> input shows nested list with numbers and their counts in sublists:
>   [[86, 4], [67, 1], [89, 1],...] output: i need to know whether a
>   number with its count is already in the list (in order not to add it a
>   second time), but the count is unknown during the for loop

There are two ways to approach this problem. First, if the list does not have duplicates, simply convert it to a dictionary:

```
numbers = dict([[86,4],[67,1],[89,1]])
```

Now each number is the key, and the count a value. Next, if you want to know if a number is *not* in the dictionary, you have many ways to do that:

```
# Fetch the number
try:
   count = numbers[14]
except KeyError:
   print('{} does not exist'.format(14))

# Another way to write the above is:

count = numbers.get(14)
if not count:
    print('{} does not exist'.format(14))

# From a list of a numbers, add them only if they don't
# exist in the dictionary:

for i in list_of_numbers:
   if i not in numbers.keys():
       numbers[i] = some_value
```

If there are already duplicates in the original list, you can still convert it into a dictionary but you need to do some extra work if you want to preserve all the values for the numbers:

```
from collections import defaultdict

numbers = defaultdict(list)

for key,value in original_list:
    numbers[key].append(value)
```

Now if you have duplicate numbers, all their values are stored in a list. You can still follow the same logic:

```
for i in new_numbers:
   numbers[i].append(new_value)
```

Except now if the number already existed, the `new_value` will just be added to the list of existing values.

Finally, if all you want to do is add to the list if the first number doesn't exist:

```
numbers = set(i[0] for i in original_list)

for i in new_numbers:
   if i not in numbers:
       original_list += [i, some_value]
```